# Python: pass ctrl-c to a process ran via os.spawnvpe

Tags: python

In my python script I have:

```
os.spawnvpe(os.P_WAIT, cmd[0], cmd, os.environ)
```

where cmd is something like `['mail', '-b', emails,...]` which allows me to run `mail` interactively and go back to the python script after mail finishes.

The only problem is when I press Ctrl-C. It seems that "both `mail` and the python script react to it" (*), whereas I'd prefer that while `mail` is ran, only `mail` should react, and no exception should be raised by python. Is it possible to achieve it?

(*) What happens exactly on the console is:

```
^C
(Interrupt -- one more to kill letter)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tutster.py", line 104, in <module>
    cmd(cmd_run)
  File "./tutster.py", line 85, in cmd
    code = os.spawnvpe(os.P_WAIT, cmd[0], cmd, os.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 868, in spawnvpe
    return _spawnvef(mode, file, args, env, execvpe)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 819, in _spawnvef
    wpid, sts = waitpid(pid, 0)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

and then the mail is in fact sent (which is already bad because the intention was to kill it), but the body is empty and the content is sent as a attachment with a bin extension.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with an try/except statement:

```
try:
    os.spawnvpe(os.P_WAIT, cmd[0], cmd, os.environ)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: No good: python doesn't throw exception, but it seems impossible to kill mail, and it gets sent as before. For some reason pressing Ctrl-C gets me to bash now. Then pressing Ctrl-C again causes EOT to appear which means that mail sent the email

Comment: How is mail behaving when you run it outside python?

Comment: on first Ctrl-C it shows (Interrupt -- one more to kill letter) and on second in quits to bash